# Need to snap scroll to section ID from top of page only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scroll

```js
window.wasScrolled = false;
    $(window).bind('scroll',function(){
    if (!window.wasScrolled){ $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:document.getElementById('aboutSection').getBoundingClientRect().top},1000)}
    window.wasScrolled = true;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--About Section--> 
<section id="aboutSection" style="margin-top: -10px;" > 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
      <h3 class="pageHero">{{ entry.heroStatement }}</h3> <!-- Button trigger modal --> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</section> <!-- End About Section-->
```

I have a landing page section at the top of my page.
I'd like the user to snap scroll past it to the next section (section#aboutSection) when scrolling from the top of the page only.

The below code works fine however it only fires once and doesn't work again if user returns to top of page and scrolls again.

In other words, I'd like to snap scroll past the landing page section every time.

I'm a newby to JS and sure there is just a few edits required to below code but have spent a couple of hours and can't get it!
Thanks all

Comment: insert your html and css, pls

Comment: <!--About Section-->
        <section id="aboutSection" style="margin-top: -10px;" >
      
      
      
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
          
                        <h3 class="pageHero">{{ entry.heroStatement }}</h3>
                       
            
                        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            
            

                    </div>
                </div>
              
           
            
        </section>
        <!-- End About Section-->

Comment: don't insert it as a comment, edit your post so that we see the behaviour.